# Microsoft365R get_business_outlook: "Forbidden (HTTP 403). Failed to complete operation. Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

Tags: r, microsoft-graph-api, azure-authentication, microsoft365, microsoft365r

I am trying to access a shared mailbox that I have read/write permissions for through my business outlook account, using Microsoft365R's `get_business_outlook` function.

```
library(Microsoft365R)

tenant_id <- "example_tenant_id"
email <- "example@example.co.uk"

outl <- get_business_outlook(tenant_id, shared_mbox_email = email)
```

The first time I try this, I get the message:

> Using authorization_code flow
> Creating Microsoft Graph login for tenant 'example_tenant_id'
> Using authorization_code flow
> Waiting for authentication in browser...
> Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
> Authentication complete.
> Error in process_response(res, match.arg(http_status_handler), simplify) :
> Forbidden (HTTP 403). Failed to complete operation. Message:
> Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

On subsequent runs, I get:

> Error in process_response(res, match.arg(http_status_handler), simplify) :
> Forbidden (HTTP 403). Failed to complete operation. Message:
> Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66964063/17701319) to a similar issue, but the use of the `app` argument doesn't help:

```
app_id <- "example_app_id"

outl <- get_business_outlook(tenant_id, shared_mbox_email = email, app = app_id)
```

> Loading Microsoft Graph login for tenant 'example_tenant_id'
> Error in process_response(res, match.arg(http_status_handler), simplify) :
> Forbidden (HTTP 403). Failed to complete operation. Message:
> Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

I have tried creating a token, with and without a `resource` argument:

```
library(AzureAuth)
# Without resource
tok <- get_azure_token("", tenant=tenant_id, app=app_id)
```

> Using authorization_code flow
> Loading cached token

```
outl <- get_business_outlook(tenant_id, shared_mbox_email = email, app = app_id, token = tok)
```

> Error: Could not find Graph host URL

```
# With resource
resource <- "https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.ReadWrite.Shared"
# Get azure token for app
tok <- get_azure_token(resource, tenant=tenant_id, app=app_id)
```

This opens a browser window, prompts me to login using SSO and brings up the text 'Not found'.

Like the poster of the linked question, I am new to Graph API and lots of the Azure terminology used, so I may be missing something obvious. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error **`403 Forbidden`** usually occurs if you don't have required **permissions** or **roles** to perform the operation.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got same error as below***

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<usermail.com>/messages
```

[image]

To **resolve** the error, make sure to add below ***Delegated*** permission and grant admin consent:

[image]

Now I generated access token again using **authorization code** flow with below parameters:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id:<appID>
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.ReadWrite.Shared
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:secret
```

[image]

When I used the above token to access shared mailbox, I got the **response** successfully like below:

[image]

In your case, make sure to grant **admin consent** for API permissions in your Azure AD application.

If you want to generate **v1 token**, then remove scope name at the end of resource in code like below:

```r
library(AzureAuth)
token <- get_azure_token("https://graph.microsoft.com", tenant="yourtenant", app="yourappid")
```

Include **version** parameter if you want to generate **v2 token** like below:

```r
library(AzureAuth)
token <- get_azure_token("https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.ReadWrite.Shared", tenant="yourtenant", app="yourappid", version=2)
```

If still the error persists, acquire **administrator** role and try the same by signing with admin credentials.

**Reference:** [Common authentication scenarios (r-project.org)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AzureAuth/vignettes/scenarios.html)